# Тире или единый знак?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, запятая-и-тире, одно-из-двух

`Никто тебя не трогает(,) живи и радуйся!`

А так?

`Никто тебя не трогает(,) ну живи и радуйся!`

Мне кажется, знак везде тот же. Но какой всë же?

Comment: Какие смысловые оттенки добавляет частица НУ?  Неясная функция, контекст нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) *Никто тебя не трОгает, **живи и рАдуйся**!*

(2) *Никто тебя не трОгает, **ну (= так) живи и рАдуйся!***

**БСП,** второе предложение является **следствием** первого. Но взаимообусловленность обозначается **присоединительной** запятой, более сильного знака для выражения данной семантики не требуется.

В конце каждой части голос **понижается**, делается пауза.

Во втором предложении есть **частица *НУ*** в качестве дополнительного структурного элемента, но она не вносит существенных изменений.